# Resource Group beginDeleteByName vs deleteByNameAsync

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

What is difference between beginDeleteByName vs deleteByNameAsync when deleting a resource group via API.

Answer (score 0):

[`beginDeleteByName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.fluentcore.collection._supports_begin_deleting_by_name.begindeletebyname#com_microsoft_azure_management_resources_fluentcore_collection__supports_begin_deleting_by_name_beginDeleteByName_String_):

> Begins deleting a resource from Azure, identifying it by its resource name. The resource will stay until get() returns null.

[`deleteByNameAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.fluentcore.collection._supports_deleting_by_name.deletebynameasync#com_microsoft_azure_management_resources_fluentcore_collection__supports_deleting_by_name_deleteByNameAsync_String_):

> Asynchronously delete a resource from Azure, identifying it by its
>   resource name.

So the first method is something like a fire and forget to delete the RG where the second method returns you an *Completable* which you can react to.